# Make rectangle into equal grids using google map SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using Google SDK in my project. I draw a rectangle for a city. I need to divide that rectangle area into equal parts and get their center point latitude and longitude in iOS.?[image].
I am expecting response like in image.I tried with stack overflow .But I couldn't get any result.I don't have sample code to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0) // the rect you draw. This is just example
let horizontalCount = 4
let verticalCount = 4
let horizontalStep = rect.width / CGFloat(horizontalCount)
let verticallStep = rect.height / CGFloat(horizontalCount)
var points: [CGPoint] = []

for i in 0..<horizontalCount {
    for j in 0..<verticalCount {
        points.append(CGPoint(x: rect.minX + (CGFloat(i) + 0.5) * horizontalStep, y: rect.minY + (CGFloat(j) + 0.5) * verticallStep))
    }
}

let centers = points.map({ mapView.projection.coordinate(for: $0) })
```

Comment: I am getting all the points with lat and long.Can you tell me how to set rectangle positions.

Comment: `mapView.projection.point(for: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` - transform CLLocationCoordinate2D to CGPoint.

`mapView.projection.coordinate(for: CGPoint)` - transform CGPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D